# VBA enable logging

Tags: debugging, vba, ms-word, freeze

The VBA code hangs MS Word, and I don't know what is the problem, I don't see any exceptions or messages, it just hangs. Is there a way to get any information about the exception? I know which line fails, but I can't step into the code because it is not a VBA code, it is in another dll. I'll attempt to attach a debugger to that dll, but what I am asking for is some sort of a MS Word log file.

Answer (score 0):

Once execution has passed into a DLL called by VBA, there's really not much that Word will be able to help you with as far as debugging.

If it's an activex dll, make sure you've got it registered properly. If it's a standard C-style dll, make sure your API declarations are truly correct for the function signature being called. Beyond that, attaching a debugging is about the only other technique. However, if you have the source for that dll, you should be able to load it into VS, and configure it to run Word, then you can debug the dll from within vs.

If you +don't+ have the source for the dll, well, yuck.